# How I can add items to the SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to make my first true application, it turns to hell in a second. First, I've tried to understand the architecture by making a number of tutorials, but different tutorials say different things about the database, and I'm a bit confused. I'd like to illustrate you where I am actually:

**My database helper:**

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_CATEGORIE = "categorie";
  public static final String TABLE_SONDAGGI = "sondaggi";
  public static final String TABLE_TESTORISPOSTE = "testo_risposte";
  public static final String TABLE_RISPOSTE = "risposte";    
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_NOME = "nome";
  public static final String COLUMN_PREF = "preferita"; 
  public static final String COLUMN_CATID = "catid";
  public static final String COLUMN_DOMANDA = "domanda";
  public static final String COLUMN_SONDID = "sondid";
  public static final String COLUMN_RISPOSTA = "risposta";
  public static final String COLUMN_RISID = "risid";
  public static final String COLUMN_SELEZIONATA = "selezionata";


  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "democracy.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

  // Database creation sql statement


  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CATEGORIE = "create table "
      + TABLE_CATEGORIE + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_PREF
      + " integer null, " + COLUMN_NOME
      + " text not null);";

  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SONDAGGI = "create table "
          + TABLE_SONDAGGI + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CATID
          + " integer not null, "+ COLUMN_DOMANDA +" text not null);";


  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TESTORISPOSTE = "create table "
          + TABLE_TESTORISPOSTE + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_SONDID
          + " integer not null, "+ COLUMN_SELEZIONATA
          + " integer, "+ COLUMN_RISPOSTA +" text not null);";


  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CATEGORIE);
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SONDAGGI);
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TESTORISPOSTE);


  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORIE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SONDAGGI);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TESTORISPOSTE);



    onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

**One of the table class I got:**

```
public class categorie {
      private long id;
      private String nome;
      private long preferita;

      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getNome() {
        return nome;
      }

      public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
      }



      public long getPreferita() {
        return preferita;
    }

    public void setPreferita(long preferita) {
        this.preferita = preferita;
    }

    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return nome;
      }
    }
```

**The datasource:**

```
public class pollDataSource {
    // Database fields
      private SQLiteDatabase database;
      private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
      private String[] allCategorieColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
          MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME };   
      private String[] allSondaggiColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA };   
      private String[] allRisposteColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SONDID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RISPOSTA, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SELEZIONATA };


      public pollDataSource(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
          }

      public void open() throws SQLException {
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          }

      public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
          }

      public categorie createCategoria(String categoria) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME, categoria);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, 0);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            categorie newCategoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newCategoria;
          } 

      public void deleteCategoria(categorie categoria) {
            long id = categoria.getId();
            System.out.println("Categoria cancellata, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          }

      public sondaggi createSondaggio(String domanda, int catid) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA, domanda);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID, catid);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                allSondaggiColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            sondaggi newSondaggio = cursorToSondaggi(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newSondaggio;
          }


      public void deleteSondaggio(sondaggi sondaggio) {
            long id = sondaggio.getId();
            System.out.println("Sondaggio cancellato, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          } 

      public Cursor getAllCategorie() {
            List<categorie> categorie = new ArrayList<categorie>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              categorie categoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
              categorie.add(categoria);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
           // cursor.close();
            return cursor;
          }


      private categorie cursorToCategorie(Cursor cursor) {
          categorie categorie = new categorie();
          categorie.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          categorie.setPreferita(cursor.getLong(1));
          categorie.setNome(cursor.getString(2));
            return categorie;
          }
      private sondaggi cursorToSondaggi(Cursor cursor) {
          sondaggi sondaggi = new sondaggi();
          sondaggi.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          sondaggi.setDomanda(cursor.getString(1));
          sondaggi.setCatid(cursor.getLong(2));
          return sondaggi;
          }


}
```

**And finally, the main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
     private pollDataSource datasource;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datasource = new pollDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        Cursor values = datasource.getAllCategorie();

        String[] categorieColumns =
            {
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME   // Contract class constant containing the word column name

            };


            int[] mWordListItems = { R.id.categoria_label };


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(),               // The application's Context object
                R.layout.single_list_item,             // A layout in XML for one row in the ListView
                values,                                // The result from the query
                categorieColumns,                      // A string array of column names in the cursor
                mWordListItems,                        // An integer array of view IDs in the row layout
                0);                                    // Flags (usually none are needed)

    // Sets the adapter for the ListView
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


       // Will be called via the onClick attribute
      // of the buttons in main.xml

      public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:


          break;

        }

      }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

I'm actually trying to understand where and how to add a method to add things to my categorie's table... I guess I should create an "insert" method, or maybe I had to call the categorie class and use the setNome... But I'm really confused... Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, null,values);` <-- that is an example of you inserting something to a table. at base level all you need is that. if you need other things inserted at perhaps other tables or columns maybe you need to make another method much like the one that this came from. perhaps being more specfic with your issue might help us. i'd assume that splitting your *datasource* and database helper might cause issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in so many different ways. Here's one:

Helper class:

```
 new Database(getWriteableDatabase()).save(someCategorie);
```

SQL Constants:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Categorie"

public static final String SAVE = "INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_NAME +
            " VALUES (NULL, ?, ?);";
```

Database class:

```
public Database(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

public void save(Categorie categorie) {
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(SAVE);

        statement.bindString(1, categorie.getSomething());
        statement.bindLong(2, categorie.getSomethingElse());

        statement.execute();

        statement.close();
    }
```

Here is another:

Use a library https://github.com/novoda/SQLiteProvider

Answer (score 1):

[These](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3Z4e7KgNdU&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A) are tutorials that helped me learn but you might need to go one or two videos back. Essentially you can add the values you'd like to insert to content values which take in the category name as their first parameter and the value as their second.